# lomerging copy pasted worksheets into one

Tags: vba, excel

i am trying to merge different amount of  worksheets into one.
This code opens any amount of file in my directory and copy/pastes each sheets called "data" in to "makrotochange.xlsm" which is my masterworkbook.

```
 Sub LoopThroughFiles()
   Dim StrFile As String
   Dim WB As Workbook
   Dim InputFilePath As String
InputFilePath = "Z:\1000_Entwicklung\05_PROJECT\0558000_CFT\055800L_CFT_Projektleitung\99_Arbeitsordner PL\Tanverdi, Yigit\SAA\"
StrFile = Dir(InputFilePath & "*")

Do While Len(StrFile) > 0
    Set WB = Workbooks.Open(InputFilePath & StrFile)
    WB.Activate
        Sheets("data").Select
        Sheets("data").Move After:=Workbooks("makrotochange.xlsm").Sheets(23)
        StrFile = Dir()
Loop
End Sub
```

Each data worksheet has columns starting from A to ZZ with different amount of rows and i want to merge these copied/pasted datasheets into a one worksheet inside my masterworkbook "makrotochange.xlsm".

How can i merge these worksheets into one?

Comment: If you were not to add new sheet for each file but rather append the imported data directly into the "master sheet" then you'd be done. Just determine the last row on the master sheet and [copy / paste](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837760.aspx) the data there.

Comment: Just take each worksheet, get the used range (not necessarily `UsedRange`), then paste into your main WS. Then, get the last empty row, and repeat.  What have you tried? A variation on this theme is asked at least once a day here, so you should be able to find some code/help by searching.  You can also skip the step of pasting to a new worksheet, and just put them all in the same one at the beginning, no?

Comment: Loop through all your worksheets in the master workbook (the "data" sheets that were created when you copied them from the remote workbooks), then copy the data in those sheets and paste into the "master" worksheet. You'll have to determine where the "last row" in the master worksheet is each time, then paste the data into the first empty row after that one. You can find many examples how to loop through the worksheets and copy/paste, and many examples how to find the last non-empty row on a sheet.

Comment: i have really less knowledge at programming, so i can read what code does but can not write on my own, thatswhy i needed the working code. My code above cant do this, if anyone can help me with the code, i would appreciate a lot

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
Sub LoopThroughFiles()

    Dim StrFile As String
    Dim WB As Workbook, rng As Range
    Dim InputFilePath As String

    InputFilePath = "Z:\1000_Entwicklung\05_PROJECT\0558000_CFT\" & _
            "055800L_CFT_Projektleitung\99_Arbeitsordner PL\Tanverdi, Yigit\SAA\"

    StrFile = Dir(InputFilePath & "*")

    Do While Len(StrFile) > 0

        Set WB = Workbooks.Open(InputFilePath & StrFile)

        'follwoing assumes your data is tabular with no empty rows/columns
        Set rng = WB.Sheets("data").Range("A1").CurrentRegion

        'exclude the header row
        Set rng = rng.Resize(rng.Rows.Count - 1, rng.Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0)

        'copy to the macro workbook at next empty row
        'NOTE: ColA must always contain a value
        '      Also assuming there's enough room for the paste...
        rng.Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: the Loop does not end, how can i end this?